# Can I run both Wine and Wine Staging on the same OS without any interference between both?

Tags: linux, debian, audio, wine, music-player

I'm asking before trying because I already have a few things set up in Wine Stable, so I don't want to mess things up by installing something else over it.

Basically, I want to install Staging because I have an app which is said to require the former to function properly under Linux (it's a music player.)

Will installing Staging affect the way Wine Stable behaves? If so, how? Can I configure Wine Stable and Wine Staging separately?

I'm running Debian Bullseye Stable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default is no. But you can use [Lutris](https://lutris.net). It is very easy to use. With it you can use different versions of Wine for different applications, what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You perfectly can by using `WINEPREFIX`:

https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Wineprefixes

---

So, here's how you go about it.

First you need two wine installations separately, i.e. two different commands to run wine, e.g. `/usr/bin/wine` for the "normal" Wine and e.g. `/usr/bin/wine-staging` for Wine Staging.

Then, whenever you want to use normal wine you just run

`wine "C:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe"`

And if you need to work with Wine Staging you do the following:

`WINEPREFIX=$USER/.wine-staging wine-staging "C:\Program Files\Another Application\Another Application.exe"`

It's all kinda tedious when running manually, so I'd recommend creating launchers or using aliases.

Now you have two "prefixes": `$USER/.wine` and `$USER/.wine-staging`.

---

If your distro does not allow to co-install wine and wine-staging you have to compile them manually and install in the directory of your choice. I've always compiled and installed wine into `/opt/wine`. You can choose whatever you want. Here's my compilation string:

```
build-wine ./configure --prefix=/opt/wine --disable-tests && make -j16 && make install-lib
```

where `build-wine` is:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

export CFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -m32 -march=pentium-m"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu"

echo "CFLAGS:  $CFLAGS"
echo "LDFLAGS: $LDFLAGS"

"$@"
```

This compiles an i686 version of it because I don't run x86-64 Windows applications. You can simply run `./configure --prefix=/opt/wine` if you need an x86-64 version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the article you sent me, I cannot find how to specify whether a prefix should use Wine or Wine Staging. Do I have to do this via `winecfg` or `winetricks`? Thanks again for you answer. It's very appreciated.

Comment: I'll update the answer, wait.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear and detailed answer. It's very appreciated. I'll try it out and then mark your answer as the accepted solution.